# actual argument cannot be converted by method invocation conversion

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, char, javac

What is the correct way to add a `char` to `charQueue` which is a `final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Character>` parameter?

Oracle seems to say that it *should* work:

> From type char to type Character

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7

code:

```
package telnet;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class InputStreamWorker {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(InputStreamWorker.class.getName());

    public InputStreamWorker() {
    }

    public void print(final InputStream inputStream,  final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Character> charQueue) {

        Thread print = new Thread() {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    char ch = (char) inputStream.read();
                    sb.append(ch);
                    while (255 > ch && ch >= 0) {
                        charQueue.add(ch);
                        ch = (char) inputStream.read();
                        System.out.print(ch);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    out.println("cannot read inputStream:\t" + ex);
                }
            }
        };
        print.start();
    }
}
```

Extract from build results:

```
-do-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/TelnetConsole/build/empty
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/TelnetConsole/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
    [javac] Compiling 11 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/TelnetConsole/build/classes
    [javac] /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/TelnetConsole/src/telnet/InputStreamWorker.java:28: error: no suitable method found for add(char)
    [javac]                         charQueue.add(ch);
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac]     method ConcurrentLinkedQueue.add(Character) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual argument char cannot be converted to Character by method invocation conversion)
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624769/ant-compile-fails-javac-compile-works-why-no-suitable-method-found-for-addch

Comment: Note that by doing `char ch = (char) inputStream.read();` you will **never** have ch < 0, so there is no point in the `ch >= 0` in you while loop.

Comment: that's ok, it's meant to be an infinite loop.  It's reading a live telnet stream:  https://github.com/THUFIR/TelnetConsole

Comment: Doh, I foolishly have class `Character` which is causing the confusion, I think.  I'm changing the class name.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, it should work fine as method invocation conversion allows boxing conversion from `char` to `Character`.
Your code compiles fine on my machine, so I suspect a NetBean specific issue.

In the meantime, you can explicit the conversion from `char` to `Character` to please the compiler. This should do the trick:

```
char ch = Character.valueOf(inputStream.read());
```

Comment: thanks, I don't feel like such an idiot.  I tried to find the syntax above, but couldn't figure it out. I'll try that :)

Comment: It's my fault, I think it's because I have a class `Character`.

Comment: No, having a Character class is valid, and `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<char>` is invalid anyway, as generics expect a class parameter (and char is not a class).

Comment: ok, I renamed the class to `MyCharacter` and now it autoboxes correctly.  I appreciate the response, it prompted me to go in the right direction.  should I accept the answer?

Comment: yeah, I fixed the Queue to take `Character` and not `char`, got mixed up renaming stuff.

Comment: Oh I didn't realised Character was a class of yours. Indeed, this was a bad idea. I don't feel like you should accept my answer, but I don't think anyone could have answered it right without that piece of information.

Comment: lol, ok, we'll just leave it like that.  thanks, though, I was really puzzled until I got your response that it **should** work, autoboxing.  Maybe it will help someone else.  I saw this error on google, but no one ever seems to know what it is (my rushed looking, at least.)

Comment: Maybe you should write an answer, explaining that boxing conversion didn't work because you `javac` got confused between `java.lang.Character` and your own `Character` class. I'm not sure this thread of comments is very clear to people coming around :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was of my own creation.  In the same package was a `Character` class which was creating, obvious now, a naming conflict.

Renaming the class to `MyCharacter` and checking that the Queue used `Character` has fixed the bug.